# What does CXX mean when make caffe?

Tags: makefile, caffe

I'm a newbie to caffe.

When I type `make` or `make test` on my `$CAFFE_ROOT`

I get a lot `CXX something.cpp`, like this:
[image]

what does this `CXX` mean?

thank you!

Comment: please do not post outputs/logs as screenshots, but rather copy-paste the actual text to your post: this helps search engines bots better index your questions/answers.

Comment: @Shai Thank you for your generous answer. I will follow your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the caffe's [`Makfile`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/Makefile#L572), the variable `$(CXX)` stores the c++ compiler executable name, and the make rule is to print (`echo`) what the compiler is going to compile.

Answer (score 1):

`CXX` means the c++/c compiler. you can choose your customized c++/c compiler in `Makefile.config`

Comment: can you briefly describe how to customize `CXX`?